# How to call class function, from another function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, linked-list

I have in my project a "Product" class, and in the main function I make new Product item-"productsListHead". In my main function I call the class "addProduct" function, which add product to the class linked-list. In order to make the program more organized, I want to devide it into functions. I want to make a function that call "addProduct" function. This is what I tried to do: 
main.cpp:

```
int main(){
    int option;
    Product productsListHead;
    do{
        cin>>option;
        if(option==1)
          products_add(&productsListHead);
    }while(option!=0);
    return 1;
}

void products_add(Product productsListHead){
    productsListHead.addProduct(&productsListHead);
}
```

this is the title of "addProduct" in List.cpp:

```
void Product::addProduct(Product* head){...}
```

It didn't work. How can I use "productsListHead.addProduct(&productsListHead);" in products_add?

Comment: "It didn't work".. What exactly are you trying and what exactly does not work?

Comment: What errors did you get? That will likely give a good idea of what to do first.

Comment: when i use "productsListHead.addProduct(&productsListHead);" in the main function, it add product. but i want to use it in another function. when code above has compilation error

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
void products_add(Product productsListHead)
```

takes an object but you call it using a pointer

```
products_add(&productsListHead);
```

BTW:
Notice that your current code passes the same object every time.

Answer (score 0):

```
void products_add(Product productsListHead)
```

this signature of the products_add function accepts a `Product Object` and not address of `Product Object`

this call should be

```
products_add(productsListHead);
```

or function should be

```
void products_add(Product* productsListHead)
```

Answer (score 0):

You passing Product by value, so temporary copy of object is created.
Read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/z6vU7k9E/

TLDR:

```
void products_add(Product& product);
```